# How to subtract two values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the difference between two fields. I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.

I have already tried

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"filter": {
"script": {
"script": "doc['students.total_fee'].value - doc['students.paid_fee'].value"
}
}
}
}
}
```

but it is returning empty "hits".

I have also tried

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"nested": {
"path": "students",
"query": {
"script": {
"script": {
"inline": "doc['students.total_fee'].value - doc['students.paid_fee'].value",
"lang": "expression"
}
}
}
}
}
]
}
}
```

and it is returning "0".

also the "script_fields" did not worked.

```
{ "script_fields" :
 { "difference" :
 { "script" : "doc['students.total_fee'].value - doc['students.paid_fee'].value"
 } } }
```

suppose I have data in following format.

```
"_source" : {
"students" : [
{
"name" : "A",
"total_fee" : 12345,
"paid_fee" : 12344.8
},
{
"name" : "B",
"total_fee" : 23456,
"paid_fee" : 23455.6
}
]
}
```

Now I want to get the difference between "total_fee" and "paid_fee" for each student.

I expect to get an array of differences for all students.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the below query and my es version is 6.2.2. It is giving a perfect result. But remember scripting is generally CPU intensive.

If you normal field then below query working fine.

```
{
   "size": 10,
    "script_fields": {
      "fare_diff": {
        "script": "doc[\"students.total_fee\"].value  - doc[\"students.paid_fee\"].value"
      }
    }
  }
```

If you are using a nested field parameter then the query would be like below.

```
{
    "script_fields": {
        "fare_diff": {
            "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source":  "int total = 0; def l = new ArrayList(); for (int i = 0; i < params['_source']['students'].size(); ++i) { l.add(params['_source']['students'][i]['total_fee'] - params['_source']['students'][i]['paid_fee']);} return l.toArray();"
       }
    }
}
}
```

Reason: Because nested documents are indexed as separate documents, they can only be accessed within the scope of the nested query, the nested/reverse_nested aggregations, or nested inner hits.

Comment: Thanks @Sounak, I will try to do that. Thanks for response.

Comment: Hi @Sounak, I tried the same in ES 6 but got 0.0 as difference.

Comment: @arpan Please send your full query. You are using ES 6 Major version? no minor version?

Comment: ```GET test-sc-ind/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "difference": {
      "script": "doc[\"students.total_fee\"].value - doc[\"students.paid_fee\"].value"
    }
  }
}``` And I am using ES 6.8.0.

Comment: @arpan please share test-sc-ind/_mappings response. So I can check the data type and your doc model.

Comment: ```{  "test-sc-ind" : {    "mappings" : {      "test1" : {        "properties" : {          students" : {            "type" : "nested",            "properties" : {              "total_fee" : {                "type" : "float"              },              "paid_fee" : {                "type" : "float"              },              "name" : {                "type" : "text",                "fields" : {                  "keyword" : {                    "type" : "keyword",                    "ignore_above" : 256}}}}}}}}}``` this is the mapping of test-sc-ind index.

Comment: @arpan I have updated the answer with details. It will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Sounak it worked for me. And the explanation is also help full.